# How to show the position of an element of an array after comparing it?

Tags: arrays, loops, while-loop

Im studying arrays for an exam that I have tomorrow and we are using C language. What Im trying to do is to ask the user for a number and then the program has to compare it with each one of the elements of the array. If it finds an occurrence, it has to show the position of the number in the array

So, what I've tried so far is to compare it with an if statement, but my problem is that I do not know how to tell the program to give the position of the element

```
    position(int array[],int size){

            int counter = 0;
            printf("write the number you want to look for");
            int number;
            scanf("%d",number);

    while(counter<size){

            if(number==array[counter]{

            }
            counter++;
    }
```

So far I have made a few attempts but all to no aval. If anyone could point me in the right direction here, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: The position would be `counter` itself which you can store in a variable or break the loop and return `counter`.

Comment: It does not seem to be working either, or I might be putting it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the counter as actual position like this.

```java
    position(int array[],int size){

      int counter = 0;
      printf("write the number you want to look for");
      int number;
      scanf("%d",number);

      while(counter<size){
        if(number==array[counter++])
          printf("position of the element: %d", counter-1);      
      }        
    }
```